# Documenting Unix commands on the command line

Tags: command-line, unix, shell, redirection

I would like to append both the last command and the output of the last command to a text file for the purpose of a tutorial.

For example: After I do an `ls` in my home directory I see this on the screen

```
bguiz@sheen:~$ ls
Desktop     Music    Documents
```

I want to then be able to enter a single command which will append the following to a textfile named `cmd.txt`

```
$ ls
Desktop     Music    Documents
```

The idea is that each time I enter a command, I can log both the command itself and its output to the same file, and after several commands, it will demonstrate a particular series of commands. I know this can be done manually - but why do that if there's an easy alternative, right?

This is what I've cooked up so far:

```
echo -n "\$ " >> cmd.txt; echo !-1:p >> cmd.txt; !-1 >> cmd.txt
```

It works, but is rather clunky, and has several gotchas such as not being able to preserve the exact screen formatting.

Is the a more elegant solution?

---

Thank you for the answers so far, but I have a requiement that it needs to work with pipe, e.g.:

```
ls -lart | grep ^d
```

Needs to get this appended in the file:

```
$ ls -lart | grep ^d
drwx------ 14 bguiz staff   4096 2010-03-03 15:52 .cache
drwx------  5 bguiz staff   4096 2010-03-03 09:38 .ssh
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[script.ksh] run with "script.ksh ls"

```
#!/bin/ksh

OUTPUT="cmd.txt"

if [[ $# -eq 0 ]];then
  print "no command to run"
  exit
fi

# dump command being run to file
echo $@ >> $OUTPUT

# run command and output stdout to the screen and file
$@ | tee -a $OUTPUT
```

Comment: @Duane, thanks for the answer. I tried it, replacing `$1` with `$@` and that worked up until  included pipes. See the edit to my main question to see what I mean.

Comment: I looked at this for a bit but a bit stumped... the problem is that the | is significant to the shell and never gets passed to the script. With modifications to the script you could get away with escaping the pipe (\|) but I assume that's a no-go.

Answer (score 10):

Rather simpler than the cleverness you've been trying:

```
$ script cmd.txt
```

do what you want to document here

then hit Control-d.

You can edit the file at a later date to add annotations if you wish, and you can use

```
$ script -a cmd.txt
```

to append more text to an existing file.

The available options seem to vary considerably between implementation.

- The Mac OS X (i.e. BSD) script supports `-k` which logs keyboard input to the command
- The GNU version (found on linux systems) supports `-c` which allows you to specify the command on the original command line, allowing you to skip the *"type your demonstration here then hit control-d"* bit
- The BSD version can *also* specify the command on the command line but does not accept a flag for that instead it must follow the output filename (which is required in this case).

Finally the GNU version warns the `vi` is not well represented in type scripts (and I imagine that this warning applies equally well to all other commands that make use of curses).

Comment: @dmckee, that's great, however I want more granular control, a command entered following each command that I want to record (not all). And I also need to be able to `echo "Something" >> cmd.txt"` In between commands as well, for annotations.

Comment: `script -a -c "some command"` followed by some command to cleanup all of the `Script started...` and `Script done...` lines looks like it could work for me.

Comment: @bguiz You can do a clean-up script so that: 
first you make a new command that echos a marker. Then later when you want an command to be recorded you run that command. When doing clean-up you can use that marker to determine which commands you want to save.

As for annotating you can do similarly a new command. It can just echo a marker with your comment.

Answer (score 5):

Write a script `script.sh` like the following were you insert annotation in the form of comments:

```
#!/bin/sh -v

# Annotating the behaviour of the ls command
ls -l

# Other comments on the next command
cmd
```

*Note the `-v` switch in the first line:*

```
-v verbose       The shell writes its input to standard error as it is read.
```

Then execute the script redirecting both stdout and stderr to the file `cmd.txt` using:

```
$ ./script.sh > cmd.txt 2>&1
```

**The file `cmd.txt` will contain the annotations, the commands and their relative output like:**

```
# Annotating the behaviour of the ls command
ls -l
total 1824
drwxr-xr-x 11 mrucci mrucci    4096 2010-02-14 18:16 apps
drwxr-xr-x  2 mrucci mrucci    4096 2010-02-20 12:54 bin
-rw-------  1 mrucci mrucci  117469 2010-02-25 11:02 todo.txt

# Other comments on the next command
cmd
./testscript.sh: 7: cmd: not foun
```

PS: remember to give execution permission to the script with:

```
$ chmod +x script.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

In the circumstances, I generally use one of two techniques:

```
sh -x script
```

Or simply run the commands and then use copy'n'paste to save the material to a file.

The 'sh -x' output doesn't include the normal PS1 prompt - it uses the PS3 which defaults to '+ ', IIRC.  And it slightly modifies the output - the details vary a bit depending on the shell you are using (so 'bash' does more messing than 'ksh' or Bourne shell do).  I seldom need more material than copy'n'paste can manage, so it is my predominant modus operandi for StackOverflow and SuperUser, etc.

Comment: Neither my Mac OS 10.5 nor my Debian Lenny boxes like `-x`. ::sigh::  The man pages make no references to any standards for script. Last vestige of the Unix wars, I guess.

Comment: I never had any problems with 'sh -x' on MacOS X 10.5 (or 10.4, ..., or currently on 10.6.2).  Which shell are you using?  'sh -x' is common across the majority of shells - I must admit, I was not aware of any that did not support it.

Comment: @dmckee: When you write 'sh -x', the shell does not do a path-based search for the script - you have to specify the path completely.

Comment: Sorry. I total misunderstood. That's what I get for checking SOFU just before bed.